# Copying S3 file with row of data containing Arabic text throws off the end of record and Copy fails

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I Unloaded a table from from Redshift to S3. The table is 212 columns wide. Some fields in some rows contain Arabic text.

Here's the Redshidt Unload command I used:

```
unload ('select * from dataw.testing')
to 's3://uarchive-live/rpt_all/rpt_all.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::12345678988:role/service-role'
GZIP 
DELIMITER '\t'
null as ''
;
```

When I attempt to COPY this file into Snowflake an error occurs.

> End of record reached while expected to parse column '"RPT_ALL"["AUTO_TRAF_RETR_CNT":211]' File 'rpt_all_250/rpt_all.txt0000_part_113.gz', line 9684, character 1187 Row 9684, column "RPT_ALL"["AUTO_TRAF_RETR_CNT":211]

The field name referenced in the error is not the last field in the records, there are two more after that one.

I removed the Arabic text from the fields and left them blank, then I attempted the COPY again, and this time it Copied with no errors.

Here's the Snowflake File Format I'm using:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS "DEV"."PUBLIC"."ff_noheader" TYPE = 'CSV' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' FIELD_DELIMITER = '\t' SKIP_HEADER = 0 COMPRESSION = 'GZIP' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TRIM_SPACE = TRUE REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE;
```

Here's the Snowflake Copy command I'm using:

```
COPY INTO "DEV"."PUBLIC"."RPT_ALL" FROM @"stg_All"/snowflk_test.csv FILE_FORMAT="DEV"."PUBLIC"."ff_noheader";
```

What do I need to configure in Snowflake to accept this Arabic text so that the end of record is not corrupted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Snowflake expert but I have used it and I have debug a lot issue like this.

My initial though as to why you are getting an unexpected EOR, which is \n, is that you data contains \n.  If you data has \n then this will look like an EOR when the data is read.  I don't believe there is a way to change the EOR in the Redshift UNLOAD command.  So you need to ESCAPE in the Redshift UNLOAD command to add a backslash before characters like \n.  You will also need to tell Snowflake what the escape character is - ESCAPE = '\' (I think you need double backslash in this statement). [There's a change you may need to quote your fields also but you will know that when you hit any issues hidden by this one.]

The other way would be to use a different unload format that doesn't suffer from overloaded character meaning.

There's a chance that the issue is in character encodings related to your Arabic text but I expect not since both Redshift and Snowflake are UTF-8 based systems.  Possible but not likely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the ESCAPE parameter on the Redshift unload and this time it worked.